# Regex to match a bibkey that contains & as part of the text to be matched

Tags: regex

I am working on a LaTeX project that contains a bibliography file (.bib) the contents of which are as follows:

`@Article{abc123,`

`@InBook{def123&233,`

amongst others. So, the specification of the expression that I would like to match are those lines that start with `@` followed by a sequence of characters (`Article` or `InBook` in the example above) followed by `{` followed by a sequence of characters, numbers and everything else possible except a `,` terminated by a `,` (this terminating `,` should be matched)

So, in the example above, I would like to have a regexp that matches:

`@Article{abc123,` and `@InBook{def123&233,`

Using the online [regexp generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/), I obtained:

`@[A-Za-z0-9]+\{[A-Za-z0-9]+&[A-Za-z0-9]+,`

but this regexp matches `@InBook{def123&233,` but does not match `@Article{abc123,` because the latter does not contain `&`.

How can I create a regexp that considers `&` as another ordinary character with no special meaning?

Comment: just add it to the group of allowed characters in the square brackets

Comment: You may use this regex: `@[A-Za-z0-9]+\{[^,]+(?:,|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
@[A-Za-z0-9]+\{[^,]+(?:,|\s*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VunVem/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `@`: Match a `@`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+`: Match 1+ of alphanumeric characters
- `\{`: Match a `{`
- `[^,]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not comma
- `(?:,|\s*$)`: Match comma or end of string with optional trailing spaces

Comment: Could you please explain by breaking down the final `(?:,|\s*$)` ? Is this something like forward backward lookahead type syntax? As in https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: No it is not a forward reference. Please check my explanation in answer for that part. It says: Match comma or end of string with optional trailing spaces